# How can i achieve grouping in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to structure my data like this.[image]

The closest function i can find is under Data/Group, but this is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: Do you mean a Pivot table?

Comment: @P.b Sir you are a true gentleman. Thank you!!!